# Set minimum size of control so all childs fit in WPF

Tags: wpf, size

Is there a way in wpf to get a panel or other controls to resize only until overlap/clipping of it's childcontrols would happen.

Example: a Horizon StackPanel with 2 controls of size 100 could be no smaller then 200 wide.

I'm looking for an easy way to do this and hope wpf supports this, because it seems a pretty common thing to ask.

If you're gonna provide an answer that tells me to go over all the children and measure them. Please give directions how to take margin into account.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
without hardcoding it yourself

Comment: MinWidth and MinHeight of the panel?

Comment: i don't want to hard code it ofcourse...

Comment: honestly question is not clear for me, could you put some images and show what you want to do?

Comment: I think you could do this with a converter on minwidth.  Children is a property of StackPanel.  For minimum I don't get how center, left, and right alignment should come into play.

Comment: correct, i realized that alignment shouldn't really matter, margin does though. Can you be more precise, does it work with other panels aswell?